# malicious attack identification using web application logs

Tags: security, web-application-security

If logs are given in a specified format and you are supposed to do investigation for a malicious activity identification , where can one start as a beginner ? is there any software which can identify malicious activity. However i am supposed to do it with Pandas, numpy etc

please give me a path where can i start my research [LOGS FORMAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxCmF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Install a logging tool like Elastic Stack. It will make viewing and searching the logged events easier. There is also Elastalert that sits on top of it and can send alerts for things like frequent repeated events in the logs.